# RTL arabic support in flash xml as3

Tags: xml, flash, arabic, right-to-left

i have flash xml template i buy from activeden but i cant show the arabic text from right to left and after a lot of research i find that textfield do not support rtl correctly and i need to convert to TLFTextfield,
My question here is how to convert classic textfield into TLFTextField in as3 ?
please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Build the textfield as TLFTextField from the beginning, and do NOT forget to include the TLF if it is NOT included.